# Pandas - Splitting text using a delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, split

Given below is the view of my Dataframe

```
Id,user_id
1,glen-max
2,tom-moody
```

I am trying to split the values in user_id column and store it in a new column.

I am able to split the user_id using the below code.

```
z = z['user_id'].str.split('-', 1, expand=True)
```

I would like this split column to be part of my original Dataframe.

Given below is the expected format of the Dataframe

```
 Id,user_id,col1,col2
 1,glen-max,glen,max
 2,tom-moody,tom,moody
```

Could anyone help how I could make it part of the original Dataframe. Tnx..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [splitting a column into multiple columns with specific name in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48207115/splitting-a-column-into-multiple-columns-with-specific-name-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 3):

General solution is possible multiple `-`:

```
df = z.join(z['user_id'].str.split('-', 1, expand=True).add_prefix('col'))
print (df)
   Id    user_id  col0   col1
0   1   glen-max  glen    max
1   2  tom-moody   tom  moody
```

If always maximal one `-` is possible use:

```
z[['col1','col2']] = z['user_id'].str.split('-', 1, expand=True)
print (z)
   Id    user_id  col1   col2
0   1   glen-max  glen    max
1   2  tom-moody   tom  moody
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `str.split`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=",")
df[["col1","col2"]] = df['user_id'].str.split('-', 1, expand=True)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   Id    user_id  col1   col2
0   1   glen-max  glen    max
1   2  tom-moody   tom  moody
```